# HTML - Разделенная на две части таблица плывет по разметке после добавления отступов в строках

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем доброго времени суток. Имею такой макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Реализовал деление таблицы на две части с помощью:

```css
.two-columns {
  column-count: 2;
  /* number of columns */
  column-gap: 200px;
  /* space between columns */
}

.two-columns table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-columns">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Комплексная мойка</td>
      <td>от <span>150</span> BYN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Мойка моторного отсека</td>
      <td>от <span>150</span> BYN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Мойка подвески со снятием локеров</td>
      <td>от <span>150</span> BYN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Быстрое кварцевое покрытие</td>
      <td>от <span>150</span> BYN</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Но теперь сталкиваюсь с новой проблемой. Задаю отступы между строками таблицы через border-spacing: 0px 30px, как на макете и сталкиваюсь с проблемой, что таблица плывет по разметке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После добавления border-spacing:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть в данном случае? Буду очень признателен за помощь в решении вопроса.

Comment: Отказаться от использования таблиц, и переделать всё на `<div>` через `position:grid` или `flex-box` это уберет данную проблему и не создаст новой когда(если) вам будет необходим отзывчивый дизайн шаблона.

Comment: Допишите весь код стилей и разметки, чтобы можно было воспроизвести то, что у вас на скриншотах